# Sql Query Update loop through Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, backend, procedure

I have a xml parameter inside my stored procedure, i need to go through and filter the values into a table

```
<Root>
  <SupplierID>3</SupplierID>
  <step Step="1">
    <Payment>1</Payment>                 
    <dayofpayment>01.06.18</dayofpayment>
  </step>
  <step Step="2">
    <Payment>0</Payment>
    <dayofpayment></dayofpayment>
  </step>
</Root>
```

This is my xml and it is passed through a variable called @Xml in the procedure. My table looks like this

+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+ 
| SupplierID | paid_step_1 | paid_step_2 | paid_step3 |
+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+
|‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌ 3‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ |‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌‌‌ ‌‌‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌  ‌‌   1‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ | ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ 0 ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ |‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌  0‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ |
+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+

i have already managed to parse the xml by using:

```sql
With XmlTable as (
Select
    Payment = Tbl.Col.value('Payment[1]', 'varchar(1)'),  
    Day_of_payment = Tbl.Col.value('dayofpayment[1]', 'varchar(10)'),  
FROM   @XML.nodes('//step ') Tbl(Col)
)
```

> My question is: how do i properly transfer the xml into the table ?

Comment: Is there possible to comes step 3 values and do you need update mode ?

Comment: Yes, that is the problem... i wish i just could insert but the client spesiffically wanted to update the values and have all pay steps in the same column

Comment: I have more couple of question. 1) How you going to pass xml to query ? 2)  can xml have bulk data ?